# How to plot two lines in the same graph if the number of observations is uneqal?

Tags: r, plot

I have two dataframes each containing a "Date" and a "Price" column.
I now want to produce a graph with two plots in it based on the observations of this two dataframes. The problem I have is that the dates are not equal. My data looks like this:

```
Date1 <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2015-08-07"), to = as.Date("2015-08-16"), by = "days") 
Price1 <- c(2.5,6.3,1.2,2.4,4.2,5.1,7.3,9.2,12.5,8.7) 
df1 <- data.frame(Date1, Price1)

Date2 <- seq.Date(from=as.Date("2015-08-11"), to = as.Date ("2015-08-16"), by = "days") 
Price2 <- c(24.3,21.2,18.4,16.2,17.1,15.6) 
df2 <- data.frame(Date2, Price2)


df1
#         Date1 Price1
# 1  2015-08-07    2.5
# 2  2015-08-08    6.3
# 3  2015-08-09    1.2
# 4  2015-08-10    2.4
# 5  2015-08-11    4.2
# 6  2015-08-12    5.1
# 7  2015-08-13    7.3
# 8  2015-08-14    9.2
# 9  2015-08-15   12.5
# 10 2015-08-16    8.7


df2
#        Date2 Price2
# 1 2015-08-11   24.3
# 2 2015-08-12   21.2
# 3 2015-08-13   18.4
# 4 2015-08-14   16.2
# 5 2015-08-15   17.1
# 6 2015-08-16   15.6
```

To create the two plots in one graph I use the following code:

```
par(mar = c(5, 5, 9, 5))
plot(df1[,1],df1[,2], log = "y", type ="l", col = "orange")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(df2[,2],log = "y", type = "l",col = "blue")
```

What I would like to receive is a graph in which the plot from df1 starts from the beginning and the df2 starts at a later point in time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass them in one data frame, so that the length of the dates is the same:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'Date1', by.y = 'Date2', all.x = TRUE)
```

And then plot, using `lines` in order to overlay the second line:

```
plot(df3$Date1, df3$Price1, type='l', col='blue', ylim = c(0, max(df3$Price2, na.rm = TRUE)))
lines(df3$Date1, df3$Price2, col='red')
```

Make sure you add the limits accordingly because the plot call is the one setting the axes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to add to a base graphics plot using `lines()` rather than `par(add=TRUE)`. And when doing this, you want to make sure the first plot draws the entire range of values so we explicitly set the `xlim=` and`ylim=` properties.

```
plot(df1[,1],df1[,2], log = "y", type ="l", col = "orange", 
     xlim=range(df1[,1], df2[,1]),
     ylim=range(df1[,2], df2[,2]))
lines(df2[,1], df2[,2], col = "blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in an approach from `tidyverse`:

```
df1 %>% 
full_join(df2, by = c("Date1" = "Date2")) %>% 
gather(key, value, -Date1) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Date1, y = value, group = key, col = key)) + 
geom_line()
```

Here is the result:

[image]